# Remove child node using lift-json

Tags: scala

I'm using lift-json 2.3 and Scala 2.8.1 to manipulate json documnts.  In the following document I want to remove a single node.

```
{
  "units": {
    "1": {
      "id":"1", 
      "name":"one", 
      "tenants": {
        "1" : {
          "id": "1",
          "name":"x"
        },
        "2" : {        // node I want removed
          "id": "2",
          "name":"y"
        }
      }
    }
    "2": {
      "id":"2", 
      "name":"two", 
      "tenants": {
        "1" : {
          "id": "1",
          "name":"x"
        },
        "2" : {
          "id": "2",
          "name":"z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can remove nodes with the remove method:

```
val js2 = js \ "units" \ "1" \ "tenants" remove {
    case JField(id, _) => id == "2"
    case _ => false
}
```

But, I need the entire document changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing is done by converting an AST node to JNothing. There's several functions to do that, e.g. 'transform'. But in this case it looks like 'replace' works best:

```
js.replace("units" :: "1" :: "tenants" :: "2" :: Nil, JNothing)
```

Comment: completely missed the replace method.  Exactly what I needed.